# Handling Dynamic Element Name Using Moxy

Tags: java, json, jaxb, moxy

I need to make a binding of my object FileDocument, which contains a reference to another object, Metadata. Metadata is -- I hope-- can have a dynamic name depending on a value on its attribute.

I have heard and used XmlAdapter (also for the Metadata class), but only for the Map case. I don't really understand how to make it work for this case.

Snippet for FileDocument:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FileDocument{
//...
 protected List<Metadata> metadata;
//...
}
```

Snippet for Metadata:

```
@XmlType(name = "metadata")
//@XmlRootElement(name = "metaCollection")
public class Metadata {
//...
    @XmlPath(".")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MetaAdapter.class)
    Map<String, String> map;
    //I'd like to have each element of metadata depend on this attribute.
    String source;

}
```

My desired output is something like

```
{ 
   "someKeyInFileDocument" : "someValueInFileDocument",
   "metadata.source1" : {
      "some key inside this metadata" : "some value inside this metadata",
      "more!": "more!"
    },
   "metadata.source2" : {
     "yes, the above key" : "looks similar but also different as the above",
     "this is another key!" : "inside this source2 thing"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)'s `@XmlVariableNode` extension for this use case:

### Java Model

**FileDocument**

We will use the `@XmlVariableNode` annotation on the `metadata` field.  This tells MOXy that instead of using a fixed name for the element/key that the name should be taken from the specified field/property on the referenced object.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlVariableNode;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FileDocument {

    @XmlVariableNode("source")
    protected List<Metadata> metadata;

}
```

**Metadata**

We will use the `@XmlTransient` annotation on the `source` field to prevent it from being marshalled (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html).

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Metadata {

    @XmlTransient
    String source;

}
```

### Demo Code

You can run the demo code below to see that everything works.

**Demo**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {FileDocument.class}, properties);


        Metadata m1 = new Metadata();
        m1.source = "metadata.source1";

        Metadata m2 = new Metadata();
        m2.source = "metadata.source2";

        List<Metadata> metadata = new ArrayList<Metadata>();
        metadata.add(m1);
        metadata.add(m2);

        FileDocument fd = new FileDocument();
        fd.metadata = metadata;

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(fd, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
{
   "metadata.source1" : {
   },
   "metadata.source2" : {
   }
}
```

### For More Information

You can read more about the `@XmlVariableNode` extension on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-json-schema.html

Comment: Good one! I thought I had to resort to Map<String, Metadata> metadata, and make an XmlAdapter for that. Thanks a bunch!